# Using less variable inside microsoft gradient

Tags: css, less

I'm having some trouble getting .LESS to recognize that there is a variable in a string. Here is my current code

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{startColor}', endColorstr='@{endColor}', GradientType=0);
```

@startColor and @endColor are both variables.

How can I place a .LESS variable inside a string?

EDIT:

I fixed it (I think..) Here is the end code that works for me

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorstr=@startColor, endColorstr=@endColor, GradientType=0);
```

Comment: It will fix your LESS code, but as stated below... I am concerned it might not actually give you a gradient in IE (I only validated this in IE8).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{startColor}', endColorstr='@{endColor}', GradientType=0)"
```

The tilda and quotes allow you actually escape code for just this situation.  I also end up using for my opacity stuff but that is because I want to reusing the word `opacity` as the function name.

```
filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{op})! important"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually fixed this problem right after I posted this, I'll edit my post to show what I did.

Comment: Actually, the single quote is required for some IE browsers.  Removing the single quote will work with LESS but IE will not pick up the gradient.

Answer (score 3):

It´s best to escape the entire filter property using: ~"filter" and wrapping the less variable (without the "@" symbol) in curly brackets.

I´ve created a mixins that properly transform a color and opacity values into a rgba and an argb values respectively:

```
.rgba(@color, @opacity) {
    @rgba: fade(@color, @opacity);
    @ieColor: argb(@rgba);

    background-color: @rgba;
    filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{ieColor}', endColorstr='@{ieColor}',GradientType=0)";
}
```